# BI Engine is disabled, but chart shows "Accelerated by BI Engine" and shows no data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bi-engine

GDS says no data for existing data source and showing icon that is accelerated by BI Engine, but BI Engine reservation was removed 2 months ago and data is available in GBQ. Changing somehow existing data source in GDS doesn’t help. Enabling, Disabling BI Engine don’t help. Only helps recreation a data source from scratch. Problem is that we need to apply new data source to each chart separately now and we have thousands of charts across different reports.
Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Please file a bug report on the issue tracker. Include project ids.

Comment: thanks @FelipeHoffa . Filed: https://console.cloud.google.com/support/cases/detail/22406972